# PDF to HTML script converter

Tags: html, pdf, converters

I have surf all the internet, but i was't able to find a good PDF ti HTML converter.
Do You know if exists a js or php script that allow me to convert a pdf in html?
Paid script or free script, both ok.
Please help me, and sorry for my english.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why? You could just use the pdf as the website.

Comment: Of course there will be no javascript library for this. Its extremely complicated. iText might do it, but partially and not very well.  Generally people are more interested in going the other way, HTML to PDF.

Answer (score 0):

If a commercial .net library (Windows only) is ok for you, try with [Amyuni PDF Creator .Net](http://www.amyuni.com/en/developer/pdfcreator/features/). The method [IacDocument.ExportToHtml5](http://www.amyuni.com/WebHelp/Amyuni_PDF_Creator_for_NET/Amyuni_PDFCreator_IacDocument/Methods/IacDocument.ExportToHTML5_Method.htm) should do what you need.

Sample code from the documentation page:

```
System.IO.FileStream testfile = new System.IO.FileStream("TestFile2.pdf", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);

pdfCreator1.Document.Open(testfile, "");

//Export all pages in the PDF file to HTML5 using the default options
pdfCreator1.Document.ExportToHTML5("test.html", Amyuni.PDFCreator.IacHtml5ExportOptions.acHtml5ExportOptionDefault);
```

*Disclaimer: I currently work for Amyuni Technologies*